# why is the minimum value is 18K but my original data has maximum value 12K

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-science, visualize

my data has a maximum value of 12K but when i visualize the data it says that the minmum value is 18K which is WRONG

the problem is with the A(s) variable
this is the code in python

```
 date   CLEARANCE   PERMITS     INSPECTION  Facilities licenses     PR  A(s)
   2020-04-01   25321   17913   16987   6631    14976                      1980
   2020-05-01   22277   22154   6588    5156    7392                       1150
   2020-06-01   32063   16542   13021   6720    18963                      2311
   2020-07-01   27345   15658   7680    5100    20947                      2096
   2020-08-01   28565   16222   6634    4652    19591                      2045


from pandas._config import describe_option
describe_option
df.hist(bins=10, figsize=(9,7), grid=False);
df.info()
```

this is the output

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 31 entries, 0 to 30
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------               --------------  -----         
 0   date                 31 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 1   A(s)                 31 non-null     int64         
 2   CLEARANCE            31 non-null     int64         
 3   PERMITS              31 non-null     int64         
 4   INSPECTION           31 non-null     int64         
 5   Facilities licenses  31 non-null     int64         
 6   PR                   31 non-null     int64         
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(6)
memory usage: 1.8 KB
```

[image]

please help thank you

Comment: What does `df.describe()` produce?

Comment: it produce the type of variable date , integer .... etc

Comment: Could you check (and eventually write) how do you read the dataframe? If you look carefully you notice that the labels now refers to a different column. (A is now the second field, and the figure seems consistent with the second field of your table, which it is not labelled A in original set). To me it is an import error.